# Javascript regex negation - Negate period on email regex

Tags: javascript, regex, email, regex-negation

I want an existing email regex to fail when entering a period (".") before the @.

This is the regex I have right now:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@domain.com$
```

These should pass:

```
test.a@domain.com
a.test@domain.com
```

But these shouldn't:

```
.test@domain.com
test.@domain.com
```

The first case starting with period is handled but second case is not.

Comment: @dan08 not if it's square brackets - then it loses its special meaning.

Comment: For real! Did not know that. comment rescinded.

Comment: @dan08 yeah - most characters lose theirs special meaning in square brackets. The ones that most notably don't are `[]` (you still need to escape those), as well as `-` which indicates a character range. However, if placed in the beginning or the end, then it's treated as a dash.

Answer (score 1):

This should work without requiring two or more characters before the @ sign.

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@domain\.com$
```

Here's how it breaks down:

```
^                  Make sure we start at the beginning of the string
[a-zA-Z]           First character needs to be a letter
[a-zA-Z0-9]*       ...possibly followed by any number of letters or numbers.
(?:                Start a non-capturing group
    \.+            Match any periods...
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+   ...followed by at least one letter or number
)*                 The whole group can appear zero or more times, to
                     offset the + quantifiers inside. Otherwise the
                     period would be required
@domain\.com$      Match the rest of the string. At this point, the
                     only periods we've allowed are followed by at
                     least one number or letter
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+@domain.com$

Comment: Note that this requires at least two characters before the @, so `a@domain.com`, for example, would fail. That might or might not be what you want.

Comment: True - I was trying to keep this close to his original regex because it seemed that he wanted it to start with a letter.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that it couldn't start with a number either. Anyway, that wasn't really a criticism, just a note about the exact meaning/implication of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: [`^[\w.+-]*[^\W.]@domain\.com$`](https://regex101.com/r/5RaKRC/1).

- `[\w.+-]*` matches any number of alphanumerical characters, `+`, `-` and `.`
- `[^\W.]` matches any character that is not a non-alphanumerical character or a `.` (which means any accepted character but `.`)
- `@domain\.com` matches the rest of the email, change the domain as you wish or use `@\w\.\w+` for matching most domains. (matching all domains is more complex, see more complete examples of email matching regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript))